# Fixes for page scroll percentage returning infinite?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to create title animations, which are triggered depending on the page scroll amount. I am using the following code to calculate percentage down the page and then animate the appropriate title:
 '''

```
var perctScrolled = 0;
//--------Scroll Percentage calc------
function amountscrolled(){
    var winheight = $(window).height(); //scrollable area of document
    var docheight = $(document).height(); //height of entire webpage
    var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    var trackLength = docheight - winheight; //total available scroll length
    perctScrolled = Math.floor(scrollTop/trackLength * 100); //amount scrolled
    console.log(perctScrolled + '% scrolled');
}
//-----title animation----
$(window).scroll(function() {
    amountscrolled();
    var scrollPosition= [125,225,250,350,450]; //percentage of the height where i want titles to display
    for(var i=0; i < scrollPosition.length;){
        var currentTitle = "#title:nth-child("+i+")";
        if (perctScrolled == scrollPosition[i]) {  
            $(currentTitle).css('left', 0);
            i++;
        }else{i++;}
    }
});
```

'''
This returns "infinity% scroll" in console when I load the site, instead of the current scroll percentage. Could anyone explain why this doesn't work/help fix my code? Thanks

EDIT: On first load of the page, "infinity% scroll" is shown in console. Can't then reload page. Could it be something to do with my loop ?

Comment: What is `pctScrolled`? can you elaborate more here?

Comment: Two things: Your variable is defined as `perctScrolled` but referenced as `pctScrolled` throughout the rest of the code. Also, what is in `section`?

Comment: My bad, should be perctScrolled. Should be a integer for how far the page had been scrolled. "section" should be scrollPosition -- changed the name so it would make more sense and forgot to change it in both places.

Comment: The function `amountscrolled` is working fine https://jsfiddle.net/jpk4c6hu/. I think it's something else. Edit: https://jsfiddle.net/9ez5dxg7/ for your code.

Comment: I believe the error is when `docHeight` and `winHeight` have the same value, which leads `trackLength` to be *0*. You can just add defensive coding for `tracklength` before letting other number to perform division with it.

Comment: @choz thanks, just added this to my code. Seems like `docHeight` is returning the window height instead of document height. I've tried several methods of getting document height none of which would work. any suggestions?

Comment: @d.Lewin With respect of your page structure, If the document's height is lower than window's, just set `perctScrolled` to `0`. If that helps what you're trying to achieve here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After several hours of pulling my hair out finally got it to work. Turns out my html was actually the same size as the window height, hence why  `docHeight` and `winHeight` had the same value. I'm assuming this is due to the overflow attributes on my HTML and body elements. I instead used the following method:

```
function amountScrolled(){
    var winHeight = $(window).height();
    var outerHeight = 0;
    var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    $('.partition').each(function() {outerHeight += $(this).outerHeight();});
    var trackLength = outerHeight - winHeight; 
    if (trackLength != 0){
        perctScrolled = Math.floor(scrollTop/trackLength * 100);
    } else {perctScrolled = 0;} 
    return perctScrolled;
}
```

The web page is broken up into sections, each one with the class `.partition` so i used these to get the full length of the page. I then used this to replace ```docHeight``. i Know this isn't the most efficient way of doing this but it is the only way i could get to work. Here is the working code:

```
var scrollPosition = [6,28,32,60,80];//array of animation trigger points
var titlesLoaded = false;//stops function being called when all animations have ran
var perctScrolled = 0;
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var scrollVal = amountScrolled();
    if(!titlesLoaded){
        titleAnimation(scrollVal);
    } returnBtnAnimimation();
});
function amountScrolled(){
    var winHeight = $(window).height();
    var outerHeight = 0;
    var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    $('.partition').each(function() {outerHeight += $(this).outerHeight();});
    var trackLength = outerHeight - winHeight; 
    if (trackLength != 0){
        perctScrolled = Math.floor(scrollTop/trackLength * 100);
    } else {perctScrolled = 0;} 
    return perctScrolled;
}function titleAnimation(){
        for(var i=0; i < scrollPosition.length;){
            $('.title').each(function(){compareHeight(i)});
            i++;
    }
}function compareHeight(iterationNo){
    var currentSection = "#section" + (iterationNo+2) + " > .title";
    if(scrollPosition[iterationNo] <= perctScrolled) {
      if (iterationNo==4){titlesLoaded=true;}
      else{
        console.log("title"+(iterationNo+1)+" in " +currentSection+ " should be moved");
        $(currentSection).css('left', 0);
      }
    }   
}
```

Need to add some validation to stop it calling constantly:
[image]